# Hide JavaScript Files in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way in Chrome Dev Tools to hide JavaScript files so that I'm only looking at my TypeScript files? Bear in mind that I'm not referring to "blackboxing" the files. Rather, I want to completely hide them in the "Sources" tab.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide them" ? _"so that I'm only looking at my TypeScript files?"_ Select the file to be viewed in center panel ? Not certain what requirement is ? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Can't you just filter the sources ?

Comment: @guest271314 Not sure how I can say it differently. I only want to see TypeScript files. I sometimes click too fast and open up the JavaScript file instead of the TypeScript file. If the former is not visible, my problem goes away.

Comment: @KennethK. Not sure following "click to fast" ? If the `JavaScript` file is opened by clicking without selecting `TypeScript` file, you can re-select `TypeScript` file ? If you only want to review or inspect a specific `TypeScript` file you can create a `Snippets` of the `TypeScript` file. You can also right-click at `More options...` and select `Go to file...` which should display a search bar where you can type in the file to load in center panel

Comment: @guest271314 I'm saying that my fingers are faster than my brain at times. When I debug, I debug using the TypeScript files (via sourcemaps). My breakpoints go in the TypeScript file. It does me no good to look at the JavaScript file. If I accidentally click on a JavaScript file, then I have to close it and click on the correct (TypeScript) file. If there is a way to hide the JavaScript files, then I won't ever accidentally click on a JavaScript file. Accidentally clicking on the wrong TypeScript file is still a concern, but the browser can't fix that ; )

Comment: @elad.chen I'm not seeing any filter functionality. I'm running version 49.0.2623.110 m of Chrome. I'm not seeing documentation to speak of either. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid clicking on a `.js` file, do not click on any files under `top`. Instead click  the `More options...` feature which should provide a `Go to file...` dialog which when selected should render an input field with a drop-down menu beneath listing all `Sources` files.

Either type in the `TypeScript` file name or select the file from the drop-down menu.

Alternatively, when `Sources` is open you can use `Ctrl+p` which should render the same input filed and drop-down menu.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the job as a workaround.